# What's a meaningful difference in scoring rule results for binary variable prediction?

Tags: scoring-rules

I'm testing several model that predict a binary variable. I've applied the logarithmic, Brier, and spherical scoring rules. Now, how do I determine what is a meaningful difference between the scores for two models? Does the low probability of a success ( <4% ) play a factor?

Comment: "meaningful" is a loaded term, implies some knowledge of costs and benefits leading to a decision-analytic approach.

Comment: Probably should have phrased it differently. I'm really just looking for some rule of thumb.

Comment: usually my models have scaled brier ~0.20 to 0.35 and assume a 10% relative increase meaningful (0.02-0.04). but this isn't even a rule of thumb, complete voodoo. (I'm in a field were c-statistic rules and tends to be much less sensitive than scaled Brier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all excellent proper scoring rules.  I have found them often difficult to interpret but that doesn't take away their value because of their high precision.  I recommend you supplement them with a high-resolution histogram of predicted risks once you establish that the predictions are well calibrated using smooth nonparametric calibration curves (e.g., using *loess* with outlier detection turned off as in the R `rms` package `val.prob` function).  Supplement the histograms with the proportion of predicted risk < 0.05, < 0.1, < 0.2, > 0.8, > 0.9, > 0.95.  Better discrimination among well-calibrated predictions means more predictions in the tails.